# How do I tell RavenDB to ignore a property but not WebAPI?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, json.net, ravendb

I have a property I don't want to store in RavenDB. If I add the JsonIgnore attribute RavenDB will ignore fine but then so will WebApi. I still want WebApi to serialize the data down to a web client though.

How do I tell RavenDB to ignore a property but still have WebApi serialize it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**In RavenDB 2.0**

```cs
using Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json

public class Foo
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Because it's using raven's internalized copy of json.net - WebApi won't pick up the attribute.

**In RavenDB 1.0 *or* 2.0**

You can customize the json serialization of your object directly using a custom json contract resolver.

```cs
public class CustomContractResolver : DefaultRavenContractResolver
{
    public CustomContractResolver(bool shareCache) : base(shareCache)
    {
    }

    protected override List<MemberInfo> GetSerializableMembers(Type objectType)
    {
        var members = base.GetSerializableMembers(objectType);

        if (objectType == typeof(Foo))
            members.RemoveAll(x => x.Name == "Baz");

        return members;
    }
}
```

Wire it up to your document store at time of initialization:

```cs
documentStore.Conventions.JsonContractResolver = new CustomContractResolver(true);
documentStore.Initialize();
```

Because it's not wired up anywhere else, it will only affect RavenDB.  Customize it however you like to suit your needs.

Comment: [Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore] alone did the trick. I can now control which properties are serialized to RavenDB separately from WebAPI. What's the need/benefit of the second part of this answer?

Comment: Raven 1.0 is still out there.  And many people don't like polluting their entities with attributes.

Comment: Thanks, the contract resolver saved me having to actually employ good software architecture ;)